# Robot Framework Language Server. Please update the related `robot.language-server` configurations. error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, robotframework

It was not possible to start the Robot Framework Language Server. Please update the related `robot.language-server` configurations.

I am unable to execute any robot tests. I am just starting with the setup in MS Visual Studio Code and downloaded the python and robot framework language server extensions.

```
OUTPUT : Getting language server Python executable.
Waiting for RobotFramework (python) Language Server to finish activating...
Starting RobotFramework Language Server with args: C:\Users\a291067\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37,-u,c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\src\robotframework_ls\__main__.py,-v
[Error - 19:06:55] Starting client failed
Error: Launching server using command C:\Users\a291067\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\src\robotframework_ls\__main__.py,-v failed.
    at serverOptions (c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\vscode-client\out\extension.js:279:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
It was not possible to start the Robot Framework Language Server. Please update the related `robot.language-server` configurations.
    Launching server using command C:\Users\a291067\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\src\robotframework_ls\__main__.py,-v failed.
    Error: Launching server using command C:\Users\a291067\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\src\robotframework_ls\__main__.py,-v failed.
        at serverOptions (c:\Users\a291067\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.40.1\vscode-client\out\extension.js:279:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2OCn.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at detailed config setup on this: https://github.com/robocorp/robotframework-lsp/blob/master/robotframework-ls/docs/config.md

Comment: While that page describes the various configuration options, it does not tell someone new to VSCode (like me) how/where to set them.

Comment: Finally figured it out... there's a gear icon on the extension's overview page in VSCode, which has the option Extension Settings. When you modify a setting for the first time, it creates the file .vscode/settings.json

Answer (score 1):

Remove RobotFramework language server, Robocorp and install only Robot Code plugin. Restart VSCode. It should work without error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

RobotFramework language server will no longer be maintained so I suggest to use RobotCode extension for VS code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)